# Collect value of a textbox linked to checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, textbox

I have a set of checkboxes, upon selection their values are added up into a string. But i also need a textbox enabled only after selection of **"input_36_10"**. The value entered in the textbox needs to be added to the string. I have trouble capturing the value being entered into the textbox. Reference of my code:     http://jsfiddle.net/WgaXj/1/

```
function updateTextArea() {
var x2 = $('.form-checkbox[id^="input_36_"]:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get().join();
$('#t1').val(x2);
}
  $(function () {
  $("#input_36_10").change(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $("#td1").removeAttr("disabled");
        var x3 = $("td1").val();
        x2 = x2 + x3;
    } else {
        $("#td1").attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });
  $('#butto').click(updateTextArea);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this in your `function`

```
   if($(this).attr('id')=='input_36_10')
        return $('#td1').val();
```

**Full Code**

```
var x2 ='';
var x1='';
function updateTextArea() {
    x2= $('.form-checkbox[id^="input_36_"]:checked').map(function () {
        // add the two lines to work it properly
        if($(this).attr('id')=='input_36_10')//Remember the id of other
            return $('#td1').val();//return the textbox value near by other checkbox
        return this.value;
    }).get().join();
    $('#t1').val(x2);
    x1 = $('.form-checkbox[id^="input_37_"]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join();
    $('#t2').val(x1);
}
$(function () {
    $("#input_36_10").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#td1").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#td1").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
    $('#butto').click(updateTextArea);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WgaXj/2/)

Comment: I've given that a try.. but for some reason i've not able to capture the value entered into the textbox

Comment: use $("#td1") instead of $("td1")

Comment: Nope.. didn't work. Maybe my question is vague, would you mind reviewing it here http://jsfiddle.net/WgaXj/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is(':checked')`

```
$(function () {
      $("#input_36_10").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#td1").removeAttr("disabled");
            var x3 = $("#td1").val();
            x2 = x2 + x3;
        } else {
            $("#td1").attr("disabled", true);
        }
      });
```